# Calculating first and last days of current week

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date, nsdate, pyobjc

Reference to pre-answered question at: [Getting first and last days of current week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625098/getting-first-and-last-days-of-current-week)

There are two answers in the above link. One of them is theoretical and the other is in a language called as PyObjC (Python-Objective C bridge language), and a quick google search confirms that PyObjC does not work with iPhone SDK.

So regarding the question, how is it possible to get the PyObjC code translated to be compatible with iPhone SDK.

Target: Supposing today (Tue.) is 19th, and Sun. was 17th (start of week) and Sat. 23rd is end of week. I want to get a string like 19/01 - 23/01 [i.e. The start of week (hypen) end of week]

Comment: Apple provides a perfect example: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an `NSDate`, you can use the current `NSCalendar` to retrieve that date's `NSDateComponents`.  Set the `NSDateComponents`'s `weekday` to 1 (the first day of the week), create a copy, and set the copy's `weekday` to 7 (the last day of the week).  Then use the `NSCalendar` to convert both the `NSDateComponents` back to their respective `NSDate` objects, after which you can use an `NSDateFormatter` to create your string representation.

This link has an example about how to get a date's weekday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057349#1057405

Comment: What if the week spans the end of one month and the beginning of the next?

Comment: @jeffamaphone the conversion from `NSDateComponents` to `NSDate` by the `NSCalendar` will handle any month rollovers.  If you're having troubles with that, feel free to post a new question, let me know, and I'll answer it.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I see now that `weekday` isn't the date but the ordinal for the day of the week.  Makes more sense now.  :)

Comment: rangeofunit - Check out the answer (not accepted answer) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681815/current-week-start-and-end-date

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code and it also checks an edge case where the beginning of the week starts in the prior month:

```
// Finds the date for the first day of the week
- (NSDate *)getFirstDayOfTheWeekFromDate:(NSDate *)givenDate
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    // Edge case where beginning of week starts in the prior month
    NSDateComponents *edgeCase = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [edgeCase setMonth:2];
    [edgeCase setDay:1];
    [edgeCase setYear:2013];
    NSDate *edgeCaseDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:edgeCase];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:edgeCaseDate];
    [components setWeekday:1]; // 1 == Sunday, 7 == Saturday
    [components setWeek:[components week]];

    NSLog(@"Edge case date is %@ and beginning of that week is %@", edgeCaseDate , [calendar dateFromComponents:components]);

    // Find Sunday for the given date
    components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:givenDate];
    [components setWeekday:1]; // 1 == Sunday, 7 == Saturday
    [components setWeek:[components week]];

    NSLog(@"Original date is %@ and beginning of week is %@", givenDate , [calendar dateFromComponents:components]);

    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

**Edit: Relevant code from above**

```
- (NSDate *)firstDayOfWeekFrom:(NSDate *)givenDate {
  NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

  NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:givenDate];
  [components setWeekday:1]; // 1 == Sunday, 7 == Saturday
  [components setWeekOfYear:[components weekOfYear]];

  return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for days ago and finally found. There is a method `rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:` in `NSDate` and do that in a simple way. You can see detail at:
[Current Week Start and End Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681815/current-week-start-and-end-date/16382322#16382322)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *weekDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *myCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *currentComps = [myCalendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:weekDate];
int ff = currentComps.weekOfYear;
NSLog(@"1  %d", ff);

[currentComps setWeekday:1]; // 1: sunday
NSDate *firstDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];
[currentComps setWeekday:7]; // 7: saturday
NSDate *lastDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];

NSDateFormatter *myDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
myDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd EEEE";
NSString *firstStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:firstDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *secondStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:lastDayOfTheWeek];

NSLog(@"first - %@ \nlast - %@", firstStr, secondStr);
```