# Current Week Start and End Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I want to get the current week start and end date and I also want to use the previous 
week start and end date and next week of the start and end date in current month.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show your effort what you try else no one have free time to do your work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solve the problem thanks for Support

Code :- it  give the current week start and end date.

```
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
 NSLog(@"Today date is %@",today);
 dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];// you can use your format.

 //Week Start Date 

 NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]        initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

int dayofweek = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:today] weekday];// this will give you current day of week

[components setDay:([components day] - ((dayofweek) - 2))];// for beginning of the week.

NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat_first = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat_first setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
dateString2Prev = [dateFormat stringFromDate:beginningOfWeek];

weekstartPrev = [[dateFormat_first dateFromString:dateString2Prev] retain];

NSLog(@"%@",weekstartPrev);


//Week End Date

 NSCalendar *gregorianEnd = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

 NSDateComponents *componentsEnd = [gregorianEnd components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

 int Enddayofweek = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:today] weekday];// this will give you current day of week

 [componentsEnd setDay:([componentsEnd day]+(7-Enddayofweek)+1)];// for end day of the week

 NSDate *EndOfWeek = [gregorianEnd dateFromComponents:componentsEnd];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat_End = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat_End setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
 dateEndPrev = [dateFormat stringFromDate:EndOfWeek];

 weekEndPrev = [[dateFormat_End dateFromString:dateEndPrev] retain];
  NSLog(@"%@",weekEndPrev);
```

Answer (score 68):

[`rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001451-SW3). It gives you the start and the interval for a certain time unit. With it it is easy to find the start of the week in the used calendar and add the range-1 to get the latest second in that week.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startOfTheWeek;
NSDate *endOfWeek;
NSTimeInterval interval;
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit 
       startDate:&startOfTheWeek 
        interval:&interval 
         forDate:now];
//startOfWeek holds now the first day of the week, according to locale (monday vs. sunday)

endOfWeek = [startOfTheWeek dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval-1];
// holds 23:59:59 of last day in week.
```

Comment: the most useful way to get the start and end as NSDates.

Comment: This would be awesome if it worked, but it renders strange results; startOfTheWeek is Saturday/Sunday instead of Sunday/Monday and at 23:00. endOfWeek is, as expected, but at 22:59:59...

Comment: let me guess: you simply log nsdate objects but you don't happen to live in GMT+0 timezone.

Comment: NSWeekCalendarUnit is deprecated in iOS 8.0, use NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth or NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear

Answer (score 16):

Here is Swift 3 Version:-

```
extension Date {
    var startOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sunday)
    }

    var endOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: sunday)
    }
}
```

You can get the week start date and end date like this :

```
let startWeek = Date().startOfWeek
let endWeek = Date().endOfWeek

print(startWeek ?? "not found start date")
print(endWeek ?? "not found end date")
```

Comment: This assumes that Monday is set as the start of a week. The current user's NSLocale can easily disagree, so this is not a robust implementation. Also see http://yourcalendricalfallacyis.com/

Answer (score 12):

#### A Swift version

of `vikingosegundo`'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16993178/649379):

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
var startOfTheWeek: NSDate?
var endOfWeek: NSDate!
var interval = NSTimeInterval(0)

calendar.rangeOfUnit(.WeekOfMonth, startDate: &startOfTheWeek, interval: &interval, forDate: NSDate())
endOfWeek = startOfTheWeek!.dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval - 1)
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what this is trying to achieve. Do you mind elaborating on the outcome of this code please?

Comment: @MarksCode it just answers the SO question :) `startOfTheWeek` and `endOfWeek` are the result.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an elegant way for Swift 3 (Xcode 8+):

```
extension Date {
    var startOfWeek: Date {
        let date = Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))!
        let dslTimeOffset = NSTimeZone.local.daylightSavingTimeOffset(for: date)
        return date.addingTimeInterval(dslTimeOffset)
    }

    var endOfWeek: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 604799, to: self.startOfWeek)!
    }
}
```

And we can use this extension like this:

```
print(Date().startOfWeek)
print(Date().endOfWeek)
```

Comment: How to calculate EndOfWeek?

Comment: @DarkTurtle I'm having a hard time figuring out what this is trying to achieve. Do you mind elaborating on the outcome of this code please?

Comment: @MarksCode this is using extension to add two custom methods to original `Date` class. It also takes care of daylight saving time.

Comment: Its giving an incorrect result for DATE - 2017-05-25 00:43:17 +0000. O/P of startDate is 2017-05-20 23:00:00 +0000. Time zone of device - Paris

Comment: @G.Abhisek that is expected behavior as 05-20 23:00 +0000 is 05-21 00:00 in Paris time

Comment: This code does not take into account leap seconds - using seconds is date math is considered dangerous.

Comment: `604799` ouch!!

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4 Solution**

I have figured out according to my requirement, where I have find out dates for following.

```
1. Today

2. Tomorrow 

3. This Week 

4. This Weekend 

5. Next Week 

6. Next Weekend
```

So, I have created `Date Extension` to get Dates of *Current Week* and *Next Week*.

**CODE**

```
extension Date {

    func getWeekDates() -> (thisWeek:[Date],nextWeek:[Date]) {
        var tuple: (thisWeek:[Date],nextWeek:[Date])
        var arrThisWeek: [Date] = []
        for i in 0..<7 {
            arrThisWeek.append(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: startOfWeek)!)
        }
        var arrNextWeek: [Date] = []
        for i in 1...7 {
            arrNextWeek.append(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: arrThisWeek.last!)!)
        }
        tuple = (thisWeek: arrThisWeek,nextWeek: arrNextWeek)
        return tuple
    }

    var tomorrow: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: noon)!
    }
    var noon: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)!
    }

    var startOfWeek: Date {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sunday!)!
    }

    func toDate(format: String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
let arrWeekDates = Date().getWeekDates() // Get dates of Current and Next week.
let dateFormat = "MMM dd" // Date format
let thisMon = arrWeekDates.thisWeek.first!.toDate(format: dateFormat)
let thisSat = arrWeekDates.thisWeek[arrWeekDates.thisWeek.count - 2].toDate(format: dateFormat)
let thisSun = arrWeekDates.thisWeek[arrWeekDates.thisWeek.count - 1].toDate(format: dateFormat)

let nextMon = arrWeekDates.nextWeek.first!.toDate(format: dateFormat)
let nextSat = arrWeekDates.nextWeek[arrWeekDates.nextWeek.count - 2].toDate(format: dateFormat)
let nextSun = arrWeekDates.nextWeek[arrWeekDates.nextWeek.count - 1].toDate(format: dateFormat)

print("Today: \(Date().toDate(format: dateFormat))") // Sep 26
print("Tomorrow: \(Date().tomorrow.toDate(format: dateFormat))") // Sep 27
print("This Week: \(thisMon) - \(thisSun)") // Sep 24 - Sep 30
print("This Weekend: \(thisSat) - \(thisSun)") // Sep 29 - Sep 30
print("Next Week: \(nextMon) - \(nextSun)") // Oct 01 - Oct 07
print("Next Weekend: \(nextSat) - \(nextSun)") // Oct 06 - Oct 07
```

You can modify `Extension` according to your need.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 6):

**Solution for Swift 5.x**

Create *Date* extension:

```
func weekPeriod() -> (startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    guard let sundayDate = calendar.date(from: calendar.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return (startDate: Date(), endDate: Date()) }
    
    if calendar.isDateInToday(sundayDate) {
        let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -6, to: sundayDate) ?? Date()
        let endDate = sundayDate
        return (startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
    }
    
    let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sundayDate) ?? Date()
    let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: startDate) ?? Date()
    
    return (startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First find the current date...

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents     = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
```

Calcuate number of days to substract from today, in order to get the first day of the week. In this case, the first day of the week is monday. This is represented by first subtracting 0 with the weekday integer followed by adding 2 to the setDay.

Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, Tuesday = 3, Wednesday = 4, Thursday = 5, Friday = 6 and Saturday = 7. By adding more to this integers, you will go into the next week.

```
NSDateComponents *componentsToSubtract  = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[componentsToSubtract setDay: (0 - [weekdayComponents weekday]) + 2];   
[componentsToSubtract setHour: 0 - [weekdayComponents hour]];
[componentsToSubtract setMinute: 0 - [weekdayComponents minute]];
[componentsToSubtract setSecond: 0 - [weekdayComponents second]];
```

Create date for first day in week

```
NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:componentsToSubtract toDate:today options:0];
```

By adding 6 to the date of the first day, we can get the last day, in our example Sunday.

```
NSDateComponents *componentsToAdd = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:beginningOfWeek];
[componentsToAdd setDay:6];
NSDate *endOfWeek = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:componentsToAdd toDate:beginningOfWeek options:0];
```

for next and previous ....

```
-(IBAction)Week_CalendarActionEvents:(id)sender{

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDate *nextDate;

    if(sender==Week_prevBarBtn)  // Previous button events 
        [offsetComponents setDay:-7];
    else if(sender==Week_nextBarBtn) // next button events 
        [offsetComponents setDay:7];

    nextDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:selectedDate options:0];

    selectedDate = nextDate;
    [selectedDate retain];

    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:selectedDate];
    NSInteger week = [components week];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM YYYY"];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];
    [formatter release];
    [Week_weekBarBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,Week %d",stringFromDate,week]];
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vikas S RajPut, Thanks for your answer which helped me to work with a week mode calendar, I followed your answer and got first and last dates for current week, and as you have written for previous and next week, I added -7 and +7 respectivly to get the dates, but I am getting it wrong. Can you help me out

Comment: Here is my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612084/creating-a-weekmode-calendar-in-ios

Comment: Hello Vikas, What if I pass here any day of week, instead of only current date, now when I tried to pass sunday, so suppose if we consider this week, instead of passing here fri, I passed here sun, so I should get mon as start of week i,e 21, but I am getting 28 as start of week, which will be monday of next week. Can you please help me out with this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code and it also checks an edge case where the beginning of the week starts in the prior month.  You can get end of week by setting `setWeekday` to `7` and you can get the prior week by subtracting `1` from `[components week]`

```
// Finds the date for the first day of the week
- (NSDate *)getFirstDayOfTheWeekFromDate:(NSDate *)givenDate
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    // Edge case where beginning of week starts in the prior month
    NSDateComponents *edgeCase = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [edgeCase setMonth:2];
    [edgeCase setDay:1];
    [edgeCase setYear:2013];
    NSDate *edgeCaseDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:edgeCase];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:edgeCaseDate];
    [components setWeekday:1]; // 1 == Sunday, 7 == Saturday
    [components setWeek:[components week]];

    NSLog(@"Edge case date is %@ and beginning of that week is %@", edgeCaseDate , [calendar dateFromComponents:components]);

    // Find Sunday for the given date
    components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:givenDate];
    [components setWeekday:1]; // 1 == Sunday, 7 == Saturday
    [components setWeek:[components week]];

    NSLog(@"Original date is %@ and beginning of week is %@", givenDate , [calendar dateFromComponents:components]);

    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for the swift4,
we can get all the days for the current week.

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())    
let dayOfWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: today) - calendar.firstWeekday
let weekdays = calendar.range(of: .weekday, in: .weekOfYear, for: today)!
let days = (weekdays.lowerBound ..< weekdays.upperBound)
                    .flatMap { calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0 - dayOfWeek, to: today) }
```

Comment: I cannot figure out why you subtract `1` to calculate the `dayOfWeek` variable.

Comment: 1 is the first day of week (`calendar.firstWeekday`).

you can replace 1 with `calendar.firstWeekday`. *Updated answer*

Answer (score 2):

```
//Begining of Week Date

- (NSDate*) beginingOfWeekOfDate{

    NSCalendar *tmpCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [tmpCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear|NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:self];//get the required calendar units

    NSInteger weekday = tmpCalendar.firstWeekday;  
    components.weekday = weekday; //weekday
    components.hour = 0;
    components.minute = 0;
    components.second = 0;

    NSDate *fireDate = [tmpCalendar dateFromComponents:components];

    return fireDate;
}

//End of Week Date

-(NSDate *)endOfWeekFromDate{

    NSCalendar *tmpCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [tmpCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear|NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:self];//get the required calendar units

    int weekday = 7; //Saturday
    if (tmpCalendar.firstWeekday != 1) {
        weekday = 1;
    }
    components.weekday = weekday;//weekday
    components.hour = 23;
    components.minute = 59;
    components.second = 59;

    NSDate *fireDate = [tmpCalendar dateFromComponents:components];

    return fireDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get current day and date by following code:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSString *weekDay = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd"];
    NSString *thedate=[dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
    //[dateFormat release];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", weekDay,thedate);
```

Now, You need to put some logic in it to calculate starting date and end date of the week. The logic will be such kind,

if the week day is Monday

then

starting date = current date - 0

end date = current date + 6

and so on

I think you can get the idea of it.

Answer (score 1):

By take advantage of the method `rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:` of `NSDate`, there is a simpler way to achieve this:

```
- (void)startDate:(NSDate **)start andEndDate:(NSDate **)end ofWeekOn:(NSDate *)date{
    NSDate *startDate = nil;
    NSTimeInterval duration = 0;
    BOOL b = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit startDate:&startDate interval:&duration forDate:date];
    if(! b){
        *start = nil;
        *end = nil;
        return;
    }
    NSDate *endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:duration-1];
    *start = startDate;
    *end = endDate;
}

NSDate *this_start = nil, *this_end = nil;
[self startDate:&this_start andEndDate:&this_end ofWeekOn:[NSDate date]];
```

So now you have the start date and end date of this week. Then last week:

```
NSDate *lastWeekDate = [this_start dateByAddingTimeInterval:-10];
NSDate *last_start = nil, *last_end = nil;
[self startDate:&last_start andEndDate:&last_end ofWeekOn:lastWeekDate];
```

Next week:

```
NSDate *nextWeekDate = [this_end dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];
NSDate *next_start = nil, *next_end = nil;
[self startDate:&next_start andEndDate:&next_end ofWeekOn:nextWeekDate];
```

Now you have them all.

Comment: What is the value used for Time Interval 10 ?

Comment: @nanjunda `this_start` is the beginning of this week, by subtracting 10 second, the `lastWeekDate` is a date of **last week**, so the `last_start` and `last_end` will be the beginning and ending of **last week**. Of course you can subtract 1 or 100 sec, just make sure the date is inside last week will be OK.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

First find the current date...

```
    let today = Date()
    let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    var weekdayComponents: DateComponents? = gregorian.dateComponents([.weekday], from: today)
```

Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, Tuesday = 3, Wednesday = 4, Thursday = 5, Friday = 6 and Saturday = 7.

```
    var componentsToSubtract = DateComponents()
    componentsToSubtract.day = (0 - (weekdayComponents?.weekday!)!) + 2

    beginningOfWeek = gregorian.date(byAdding: componentsToSubtract, to: today)

    var componentsToAdd: DateComponents? = gregorian.dateComponents([.day], from: beginningOfWeek!)
    componentsToAdd?.day = 6
    endOfWeek = gregorian.date(byAdding: componentsToAdd!, to: beginningOfWeek!)

    let components: DateComponents? = gregorian.dateComponents([.month], from: beginningOfWeek!)
    let month: Int? = components?.month

    let components1: DateComponents? = gregorian.dateComponents([.month], from: endOfWeek!)
    let month1: Int? = components1?.month

    print("\(month) - \(month1)")

    showDate(start:beginningOfWeek!, end:endOfWeek!, strtMn:month!, endMn:month1!)

func showDate(start:Date, end:Date, strtMn:Int, endMn:Int) {
    if strtMn == endMn{
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
        let stringFromDate: String = formatter.string(from: start)

        let formatter1 = DateFormatter()
        formatter1.dateFormat = "dd"
        let stringFromDate1: String = formatter1.string(from: end)
        print("\(stringFromDate) - \(stringFromDate1)")
        lblDate.text = "\(stringFromDate) - \(stringFromDate1)"
    }
    else{
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
        let stringFromDate: String = formatter.string(from: start)

        let formatter1 = DateFormatter()
        formatter1.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
        let stringFromDate1: String = formatter1.string(from: end)
        print("\(stringFromDate) - \(stringFromDate1)")
        lblDate.text = "\(stringFromDate) - \(stringFromDate1)"
    }
}
```

for next and previous ....

```
@IBAction func week_CalendarActionEvents(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    var offsetComponents = DateComponents()
    var nextStrtDate: Date?
    var nextEndDate: Date?
    var startDate: Date?
    var endDate: Date?

    startDate = beginningOfWeek
    endDate = endOfWeek

    if sender.tag == 1 {
        offsetComponents.day = -7
    }
    else if sender.tag == 2 {
        offsetComponents.day = 7
    }

    nextStrtDate = gregorian.date(byAdding: offsetComponents, to:startDate!)
    startDate = nextStrtDate
    beginningOfWeek = startDate

    nextEndDate = gregorian.date(byAdding: offsetComponents, to: endDate!)
    endDate = nextEndDate
    endOfWeek = endDate

    let components: DateComponents? = gregorian.dateComponents([.month], from: startDate!)
    let month: Int? = components?.month

    let components1: DateComponents? = gregorian.dateComponents([.month], from: endDate!)
    let month1: Int? = components1?.month

    print("\(month)- \(month1)")

    showDate(start:startDate!, end:endDate!, strtMn:month!, endMn:month1!)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3+: Simple solution with extension**

```
extension Date {
    var startOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sunday)
    }

    var endOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: sunday)
    }

    var yesterdayDate: Date? {
        return NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: noon)!
    }

    var tommorowDate: Date? {
        return NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: noon)!
    }

    var previousDate: Date? {
        let oneDay:Double = 60 * 60 * 24
        return self.addingTimeInterval(-(Double(oneDay)))
    }

    var nextDate: Date? {
        let oneDay:Double = 60 * 60 * 24
        return self.addingTimeInterval(oneDay)
    }

    var noon: Date {
        return NSCalendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)!
    }

    var month: Int {
        return Calendar.current.component(.month,  from: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

If you want to show the current week dates, here is the code.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for dateIndex in 0..<7 {
            guard let startWeek = Date().startOfWeek else { return }
            let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: dateIndex + 1, to: startWeek)
            print(date)
        }

}



extension Date {
    var startOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sunday)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3.0

```
let cal = NSCalendar.current


//weekday
let weekday = cal.component(.weekday, from: Date())

var dateComp = cal.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second, .day, .month, .year], from: Date())
print(dateComp.day!)


//Start Date of the week - Sunday
dateComp.day = dateComp.day! - (weekday - 1)// start date of week

print(cal.date(from: dateComp)!)


//End Date of the Week - Saturday
dateComp = cal.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second, .day, .month, .year], from: Date())


dateComp.day = dateComp.day! + (7 - weekday)

print(cal.date(from: dateComp)!)
```

Answer (score 0):

- There are 3 steps to get `Start date` and `End date` of week from any region.

1. Find week day of current day.

```
func getTodayWeekDay() -> String {
       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
       let weekDay = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
       return weekDay
}
```

2. Make emun class for `subtraction` and `addition` of days.

> i.e. if current week day is `Wednesday` then for getting `Monday` of current week we have to subtract `-2` from current day.
> And for getting `Sunday` of current week we have to add `4` into current day.

```
enum WeekDays: String {
    case monday = "Monday"
    case tuesday = "Tuesday"
    case wednesday = "Wednesday"
    case thursday = "Thursday"
    case friday = "Friday"
    case saturday = "Saturday"
    case sunday = "Sunday"
    
    var daysToSubstract: Int {
        switch self {
        case .monday: return 0
        case .tuesday: return -1
        case .wednesday: return -2
        case .thursday: return -3
        case .friday: return -4
        case .saturday: return -5
        case .sunday: return -6
        }
    }
    
    var daysToAdd: Int {
        switch self {
        case .monday: return 6
        case .tuesday: return 5
        case .wednesday: return 4
        case .thursday: return 3
        case .friday: return 2
        case .saturday: return 1
        case .sunday: return 0
        }
    }
}
```

1. Get `Start-week` and `End-week` by `subtraction` and `addition` from current day.

```
extension Date {
    var startOfWeek: String? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let startWeek = dateFormatter.string(from:gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: WeekDays(rawValue: getTodayWeekDay())?.daysToSubstract ?? 0, to: self)!)
        print("start-week--- \(startWeek)")
        return startWeek
    }

    var endOfWeek: String? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let endWeek = dateFormatter.string(from:gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: WeekDays(rawValue: getTodayWeekDay())?.daysToAdd ?? 6, to: self)!)
        print("end-week--- \(endWeek)")
        return endWeek
    }
}
```

- You can use functions like below:

```
Date().startOfWeek
Date().endOfWeek
```