# UITableview title bar with date for week?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I have the title of `UITableview` with date?

I know I can edit the title using:

```
self.title=@"meals for ..";
```

I want to add the date for one week. How can I do that?

Comment: What is a "date for 1 week"?

Comment: self.title=@"meals for ..";  That's the best effort you've made so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a date like this:

```
NSDate *theDateToday = [NSDate date];
```

And format it like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd"];
NSString *theDateAsAString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:theDateToday];
```

Combine that with what you have like this:

```
self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"meals for %@", theDateAsAString];
```

---

As for finding the days of the week, you could try adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681815/current-week-start-and-end-date).

```
- (NSString *)getWeekStartDateAsString:(NSDate *)date {

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

    int dayofweek = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:today] weekday];// this will give you current day of week

    [components setDay:([components day] - ((dayofweek) - 2))];// for beginning of the week.

    NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat_first = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat_first setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    dateString2Prev = [dateFormat stringFromDate:beginningOfWeek];

    weekstartPrev = [[dateFormat_first dateFromString:dateString2Prev] retain];

    return weekstartPrev;

}

- (NSString *)getWeekEndDateAsString:(NSDate *)date {

    NSCalendar *gregorianEnd = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *componentsEnd = [gregorianEnd components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

    int Enddayofweek = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:today] weekday];// this will give you current day of week

    [componentsEnd setDay:([componentsEnd day]+(7-Enddayofweek)+1)];// for end day of the week

    NSDate *EndOfWeek = [gregorianEnd dateFromComponents:componentsEnd];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat_End = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat_End setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    dateEndPrev = [dateFormat stringFromDate:EndOfWeek];

    weekEndPrev = [[dateFormat_End dateFromString:dateEndPrev] retain];

    return weekEndPrev;

}
```

You end result might look like this:

```
self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"meals for %@-%@", [self getWeekStartDateAsString:theDateToday], [self getWeekEndDateAsString:theDateToday]];
```

Comment: am getting error with this line                                   NSDate *theDateAsAString  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:theDateToday ];

Comment: Yes, probably `viewDidLoad`would be a good place. What is the error?

Comment: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSDate *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSString *'

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had some typos. Thanks @Roshan!

Comment: OKY NOW WORK BUT how can i have the date for 7 day example From 2-5june 2013??and then the back button of details page will change ,can then i customize t?

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11716580/1415038) has a possible solution.

Comment: @woz, may have a look on my answer to see, how you can achieve this much easier by using NSCalendar's `rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:`

Answer (score 0):

A rarely known NSCalendar method will be the best option IMO

[`rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001451-SW3). It gives you the start and the duration (interval) for a certain time unit. With it it is easy to find the start of the week in the used calendar and add the range-1 to get the latest second in that week.

With the also rarely seen [`localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:` <sub>Available in OS X v10.6, iOS 4.0</sub>](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-SW52) it is easy to create a localized representation of the dates.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startOfTheWeek;
NSDate *endOfWeek;
NSTimeInterval interval;
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit 
       startDate:&startOfTheWeek 
        interval:&interval 
         forDate:now];
//startOfWeek is 2013-06-02 22:00:00 +0000 now (note: it is GMT with timezone support for my timezone Europe/Berlin/DST)

endOfWeek = [startOfTheWeek dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval-1];
// 2013-06-09 21:59:59 +0000

NSString *text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:startOfTheWeek 
                                                dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle 
                                                timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
text = [text stringByAppendingString:@" to "];
text = [text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:endOfWeek 
                                                                           dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle 
                                                                           timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle]];

self.title=text;
```

results in `03.06.13 to 09.06.13` for my german locale, where Monday is start of the week.