# Get weeks date in IOS SDK

Tags: ios, calendar, nscalendar

I want to get the current & next week dates with day name.

i.e. If today's date is 28-06-2013 (Friday) then I want to get the dates from 23-06-2013(sunday) to 29-06-2013 (Saturday) as the **this current week.**

**for next week**
I want to get dates from 30-06-2013(sunday) to 06-07-2013 (saturday).

How can I do this?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you want this limited dates in UIDatepicker Or you just want the dates for any other function?

Comment: @wesley, I not using the datePicker.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is sample code that does the trick.

```
-(NSArray*)daysThisWeek
{
     return  [self daysInWeek:0 fromDate:[NSDate date]];
}

-(NSArray*)daysNextWeek
{
    return  [self daysInWeek:1 fromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
-(NSArray*)daysInWeek:(int)weekOffset fromDate:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    //ask for current week
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    comps=[calendar components:NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    //create date on week start
    NSDate* weekstart=[calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
    if (weekOffset>0) {
        NSDateComponents* moveWeeks=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        moveWeeks.week=1;
        weekstart=[calendar dateByAddingComponents:moveWeeks toDate:weekstart options:0];
    }

    //add 7 days
    NSMutableArray* week=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];
    for (int i=1; i<=7; i++) {
        NSDateComponents *compsToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        compsToAdd.day=i;
        NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:compsToAdd toDate:weekstart options:0];
        [week addObject:nextDate];

    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:week];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply....Great! It works. But how can I get the dates for the Next week also?

Comment: How can i also get the day (i.e. Sunday,Monday,etc.)? I tried a lot but always gives me the next day (i.e. prints Monday instead of Sunday) like for 2013-06-30 18:30:00 +0000 date.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to copy and paste an answer, but I'd suggest going and reading this post: [Current Week Start and End Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681815/current-week-start-and-end-date). It looks like it'll help you achieve what you want to.

Something like this perhaps:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSInteger weekNumber =  [[calendar components: NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:now] week];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
[comp setWeek:weekNumber];  //Week number.

int i;

for (i = 1; i < 8; i=i+1){

    [comp setWeekday:i]; //First day of the week. Change it to 7 to get the last date of the week

    NSDate *resultDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, yyyy"];

    NSString *myDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:resultDate];
    NSLog(@"%@",myDateString);

}
```

Comment: Once you have the start, and end date, you could just iterate through and fill in the blanks.

Comment: Updated my answer to include a solution. This gives you all 7 dates in the week.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSDateComponents` to find out the day of the week and then to find the date required before and after it.

Comment: Check the link in @HeftyHijacker answer for appropriate code.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, I'm not an expert on this or anything, but a dumb way to do this is to first be able to recognize the day of the week from `NSDate`. Then you could add in `if` statements then the if statements could add and subtract the dates and `nslog` or `printf` each of them. Or I think there is a way by accessing the ios calendar.

okay so the above pretty much said and did more than what I said. Yeah go check the link on the post before me.

Answer (score 0):

Use an NSCalendar instance to convert your start NSDate instance into an NSDateComponents instance, add 1 day to the NSDateComponents and use the NSCalendar to convert that back to an NSDate instance. Repeat the last two steps until you reach your end date.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
 NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
 NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
 [comps setDay:1];
 NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
```

Or else find start date and end date. like

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:7];
 NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
```

then,
NSDate nextDate;

```
for ( nextDate = startDate ; [nextDate compare:endDate] < 0 ; nextDate = [nextDate addTimeInterval:24*60*60] ) {
  // use date
}
```

Comment: your code gets the 7 days following the current date(next 7 days from now on), which is not what OP asks for