# how to get all start dates for all weeks in a year

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I need to get all start dates for all weeks in a year, I have tried following code , but i have no clue how to figure out exactly the actual start date for each week.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *compStart = [cal components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit  |NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:startDate];

[compStart setDay:1];
[compStart setMonth:1];

NSDate* weekstart=[cal dateFromComponents:compStart];

for(int i=0; i < 52; i++)
{
    NSDateComponents* moveWeeks=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    moveWeeks.week=1;
    weekstart=[cal dateByAddingComponents:moveWeeks toDate:weekstart options:0];
    [arrayWeeks addObject:weekstart];

}
```

Comment: In your for loop, what are your current results? What is put into arrayWeeks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this link has answered my question, I m passing weekOffset from 0-51 and did the job

[Get weeks date in IOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358928/get-weeks-date-in-ios-sdk?lq=1)

the code needs a little modification so here is the modified code which is correct one for me

```
-(void)initArrayWeeks
{
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *compStart = [cal components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit |         NSSecondCalendarUnit  |NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:startDate];

[compStart setDay:1];
[compStart setMonth:1];

NSDate* weekstart=[cal dateFromComponents:compStart];

for(int i = 0; i<51; i++)
{
    NSArray *days = [self daysInWeek:i fromDate:weekstart];
    [arrayWeeks addObject:days[0]];
}


}
-(NSArray*)daysInWeek:(int)weekOffset fromDate:(NSDate*)date
{
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

//ask for current week
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comps=[calendar components:NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
//create date on week start
NSDate* weekstart=[calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
if (weekOffset>0) {
    NSDateComponents* moveWeeks=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    moveWeeks.week=weekOffset;
    weekstart=[calendar dateByAddingComponents:moveWeeks toDate:weekstart options:0];
}

//add 7 days
NSMutableArray* week=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];
for (int i=1; i<=7; i++) {
    NSDateComponents *compsToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    compsToAdd.day=i;
    NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:compsToAdd toDate:weekstart options:0];
    [week addObject:nextDate];

}
return [NSArray arrayWithArray:week];
}
```