# Removing NSDate's with same day from NSArray

Tags: uitableview, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdate

I'm trying to come up with the best / cleanest way to do this.

Basically I have an array of NSDates, and I'm trying to get the UITableView Delegate methods (numberOfSectionsInTableView) to return the number of dates in the array that aren't the same.

So here's another example:

My array:

```
NSDate *1 (Monday 1st Jan)
NSDate *2 (Monday 1st Jan)
NSDate *3 (Tuesday 2nd Jan)
NSDate *4 (Wednesday 3rd Jan)
NSDate *5 (Wednesday 3rd Jan)
```

The array I would like:

```
NSDate *1 (Monday 1st Jan)
NSDate *2 (Tuesday 2nd Jan)
NSDate *3 (Wednesday 3rd Jan)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is to pass you dates array in a set and then again into an array, but you loose sorting.

By definition [`NSSet`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsset?language=objc) can contain only one instance of equal instances.

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray: datesArray];
```

By calling `isEqual` to one of each elements is guaranteed that you can't have duplicated dates. `isEqual` in a `NSDate` calls `isEqualToDate` that considers equality only if the instances represent the same date. 
Then:

```
NSArray * newdates = set.allObjects
```

Is worth to mention that on NSArray you can also use KVC to make a distinct union:

```
NSArray * uniqueDates = [datesArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```

Comment: Preferable [NSOrderedSet](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsorderedset?language=objc)

Comment: Sure, sometimes I forgot it. @vikingosegundo

Comment: upvote for mentioning `distinctUnionOfObjects`. One thing worth mentioning is that the dates must have the same time components, otherwise they won't be deemed equal.

Comment: Is there any way of removing the time components as I'm only after the dates? @vikingosegundo

Comment: sure. please search for it on SO.

Comment: here is one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16993178/106435 exchange `NSWeekCalendarUnit` with `NSCalendarUnitDay`. Basically you don't remove time components , but set them to midnight in your current timezone.